# How to access the second character in a three-digit int?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Enter a three-digit number: ");
int num = sc.nextInt();
int digit1 = num / 100;
//int digit2 = ?
int digit3 = num % 10;
```

I need to find the 2nd digit in this three-digit number and then I have to check
if the number can be divided by each one of its digits. How can I get the 2nd digit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you could parse it to a string and get the numbers that way like:

```
int num = ...;
string numbS = Integer.toString(num);
char char1 = numbS.charAt(0);
int num1 = Character.getNumericValue(char1);
```

Or you could do it by dividing by 10 and then the remainder of ten:

```
int digit2 = (num / 10) % 10;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You should rather explain the problem(s) and how your solution tackles/solves this problem(s).

Answer (score 3):

That is just `(num / 10) % 10`.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You should rather explain the problem(s) and how your solution tackles/solves this problem(s).

Comment: @Turing85, I'm aware that's the general rule, but this was a pretty simple problem in this specific case, and given the code the OP already had for getting the first and third digits, I figured how my answer solves the problem would be fairly apparent to someone who had already done the other two digits.

Comment: Well... [you figured wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641127/how-to-get-the-3rd-digit-of-a-four-digit-integer).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we have the base-10 integer x = 12345. We can perform a modulus operation x%10 to get a remainder of 5. That'll work for giving us the one's digit. What about the ten's place? Integer division x/10 gives us 1234. Then we can do the modulus operation and get the ten's place, x/10%10 = 4. To get the hundred's place, we divide by 100 first, and so on.

The general formula is x/10^(digit's index)%10, where a number's rightmost digit is located at index 0.