# How to get the 3rd digit of a four-digit Integer?

Tags: java

So, earlier today I asked how to get the 2nd digit of a three-digit integer. Now I need to get the third digit in a four-digit integer. How do I do that? I need to write a program that the user inputs a four-digit number and I have to get the first and the last digit, the second and the third digit aswell and with them to form two new numbers. Then I have to compare the two new numbers. Also if somebody could tell me how can I add those 2 digits together (not addition), but to set them next to each other. For example, the given number is **1234** - I need to get **14** and **23**. I've tried `int firstNum = firstDigit + "" + fourthDigit` but it doesn't let me because that's a String and I need an int. (I'm new to Java.)

Comment: Then don't use an int, use a string. A tutorial would probably be a better starting place than just asking everything here.

Comment: Your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638042/how-to-access-the-second-character-in-a-three-digit-int) (and its answers), together with this question is a perfect example why code-only answers are discouraged. Both answers do not explain how they solve them, thus you were not able to solve a transfer-knowledge question. I highly recommend to solve this one on your own, even if it takes time. Software Engineering is a craftmansship. The learning process includes failing, and lots of it.

Comment: I mean.. I'm in a course for Java EE and we haven't gotten to Strings yet, so I don't know if I should use it. That's why I want to do it this way and I don't know how. And I can't seem to find anything on the web so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: "*I mean.. I'm in a course for Java EE and we haven't gotten to Strings yet...*" - I would not expect a JEE course to cover `String`s. JEE is an advanced topic. Normally, one expects that students know the basics of Java (i.e. the core language features and the core libraries) before enrolling for an advanced course. Have you checked the prerequisites of this course?

Comment: They teach us everything from the beginning. You don't need any knowledge in this area to join there. Hell.. they even explained what computers are..

Comment: Splitting a number into its separate digits is a task taught in basic math courses, so it doesn't look so far of to start the course by explaining the computer when you need to ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In anticipation that it will be needed, here is how you get all the digits of a number.

```java
      long value = Long.MAX_VALUE;

      System.out.println(value);

      while (value != 0) {
         // get the remainder when divided by 10
         int digit = (int) (value % 10);
         System.out.print(digit + " ");
         // now divide value by 10 to position for next digit.
         value /= 10;
      }
      System.out.println();
```

Note that they are printed in reverse order.

You can also do them individually

```java
      first digit  =  x % 10
      second digit = (x/10) % 10
      third digit  = (x/100) % 10
        and so on
```